# Can not find symbol class

Tags: android

In my android main activity I am trying to create a setOnClickListener function, where I just pass the button name and the activity class, to decrease the line of code but get the error.

**error:**
Can not find symbol class className

```
public void startActivity(ImageButton buttonName, Class className){

            buttonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, className.class);
                    startActivity(intent); // startActivity allow you to move
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Don't know why the symbols wasn't found at all. However, at a minimum, the `className` parameter needs to be marked `final` for it to be used in an anonymous inner class like that. You might also want to declare it to be of type `Class<?>` instead of a raw type. Did you clean and recompile? Also the code doesn't make a lot of sense. The value  of `className.class` is going to be `Class`, which isn't going to be a good match to the second parameter for the `Intent` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an extra `.class` because it's already there :)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, className);
```

However you shouldn't use a raw type `Class`. It's better to replace it with a wildcard `Class<?>` at least. But it's still a bad solution because you can call `startActivity(image_button, Object.class)`, and it will compile and throw an error at the runtime. I suggest you to use this function:

```
public void startActivity(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Class<? extends Activity> activity){
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity);
            startActivity(intent); // startActivity allow you to move
        }
    });
}
```